# Powershell Find-Module not finding all versions

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I am using PS 5.1 under Win 10.

`Find-Module` for `PSColor` is finding only version 1.0.0.0 (see below).
But https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSColors/1.3.0
shows there are many more.

**Why?**
**How can I get it detect all versions?**
**How can I programatically tell this is happening (for any package)?**

```
> Find-Module -Name 'PSColor' -Repository 'PSGallery' -AllVersions

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
1.0.0.0    PSColor                             PSGallery            Provides basic color highlighting for files, services, select-string etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its the PSColor that is not properly setup in the PSGallery. If you do exactly the same thing on another module you will see that you will get all versions.

So in this case I don´t think the solution is on your side.

Comment: It was my mistake, I was mixing PSColor with PSColors.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I was mixing packages [`PSColor`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSColor) (also [this](https://github.com/Davlind/PSColor)) with [`PSColors`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSColors) (also [this](https://github.com/ecsousa/PSColors)).

Similar names, and there is yet [`PSColorizer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSColorizer).